# Windows Server - Disk full but isn't?

Tags: windows-server-2012

Never had to ask on a forum about Windows before but this one has my head scratching.

The issue is the error message 'There is not enough space on [NETWORK SHARE]'. The server has 10TB disk space and only 4TB used. The error states I need to free up the exact size of the file I am trying to transfer. I had this error yesterday and after about 5 restarts it's cleared but it's now back today.

See here for space available:

[image: See here for space available]

And the error message:

[image: the error message]

I've checked effective access for the network shares and this is only happening when accessing the share from a remote computer. If I manage files locally on the server all is fine.

Any idea's? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The network share has perhaps a 'quota' maximum enabled for your user account. See [Quota management](https://blog.foldersecurityviewer.com/quota-management-in-windows-server-2016/).

Comment: No quotas are setup for any of the shares, the first thing I checked!

Comment: Is the server disk is a storage pool? Is it possible that the storage pool is out of space even though the disk is not?

Comment: From any remote computer?

Comment: Yes, any remote computer is effected. The storage pool still has space left in it.